# How do I get started with customizing Bootstrap 3 with LESS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've just downloaded Bootstrap 3 from https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap. I'm watching this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6EPArp4csA. How exactly do I get started with modifying the LESS files?

What I did was to copy these directories: LESS, dist/css dist/fonts dist/js and create my new project. The current project folder looks like this:

```
css
less
js
index.html
```

with the HTML file having this at the top:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="less/my_site.less"/> //only contains @import "bootstrap.less";
<script src="js/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now when I try to modify one of the variables in variables.less and compile it with SimpLESS there's a Syntax Error: carousel.less. What gives? When I comment out "carousel.less", another problem pops up with dropdown.less. So maybe it has something to do with the mixins? Anybody have an idea on how I get started on moving on with this?

Comment: You may want to try WinLESS that can actually compile Boostrap 3.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo on a Mac so I can't use WinLESS, I did use it for Bootstrap 2.x though, no pain at all to get it started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit: Jan 14, 2015**

### Using gulp

1. Make sure you have node installed from nodejs.org

   1.1: Own `/usr/local` so you can run npm commands without sudo:

   `` sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local ``
2. Install gulp globally: `npm install gulp -g`
3. Make a folder on desktop and go to it: `cd ~/Desktop && mkdir boot-gulp && cd $_`.
4. Initiate the project manifest: `npm init` and accept the defaults.
5. Install gulp and gulp-less: `npm install gulp gulp-less`.
6. Make a file called `gulpfile.js` and paste the following in that file:

`gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var less = require("gulp-less");

gulp.task("less", function() {
   gulp.src("less/main.less")
       .pipe(less())
       .pipe(gulp.dest("css"));
});
```

7. Install bower globally: `npm install bower -g`
8. Install bootstrap with bower: `bower install bootstrap`
9. Make the `less/main.less` file and load `bootstrap.less`:

`less/main.less`

```
@import "bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
// overrides here
@primary: #000; 
// ...
```

10. Run `gulp less` and you should see the output in the css folder.

#### Adding watch

11. Add the `gulp-watch` plugin: `npm install gulp-watch`
12. Update `gulpfile.js` to watch any less file and automatically compile to css:

`gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var less = require("gulp-less");
var watch = require("gulp-watch"); //+

gulp.task("less", function() {
  watch("less/**/*.less", function(){ //+
    gulp.src("less/main.less")
       .pipe(less())
       .pipe(gulp.dest("css"));
  }); //+
});
```

Now run `gulp less`. It is now watching all the less files in the `less` folder. Make a change and save any file in the `less` folder, and you should see the output automatically in the `css` folder.

**EDIT: Jan 1, 2014**

Give [Koala](http://koala-app.com/) a try. It compiles your LESS files real-time. It is free and cross-platform. You might also want to take a look at this FAQ about [compiling Bootstrap with Koala.](https://github.com/oklai/koala/wiki/Unable-to-build-Less-Bootstrap-in-Koala-1.4)

**Original Answer**

I reproduced your problem with the app you mentioned. I tried another app such as **[crunch app](http://crunchapp.net/)** and it worked fine. So with crunch, just drag and drop the `bootstrap.less` file into that app and click on `crunch file` button on the top right corner of the app. Then it will ask you where to save it. I personally use the command line tool assets-packager (`npm install -g assets-packager`). I hope that helped.

Comment: Oh my thank you. It worked. :) Now I just have to find a way to automate the crunching process.

Comment: That's the point that you will need an app that watches your work. I personally use yeoman.io which is a front-end development workflow manager and beyond. The installation might give you a headache though if you don't have all the requirements.

Comment: Christ yeah I've been hearing about that, I will most probably use it in the future, but one step at a time first, I'm just building a prototype anyway. Do you know any good resources/tutorials?

Comment: The tutorial on their site is a good starting point (it is at the bottom of the homepage)

Comment: Crunch requires adobe air. Don't pollute your system with junk software like this. Winless in the comment above is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

These are some of the better tutorial I could find about Bootstrap 3 Less Workflow.

1. http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-less-workflow-tutorial
2. http://bootstrap.lesscss.ru/less.html

And if you want to learn Less, you can refer these links

1. http://lesscss.org  (the official less website)
2. http://groupdocs.com/blog/using-bootstrap-with-less-css-tutorial
3. http://designshack.net/articles/css/using-less-js-to-simplify-your-css3

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a php server, just install **lessphp**:

### [lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/#quick_start)

and then add this to your first line:

```
<?php
    require "lessc.inc.php";
    $less = new lessc;
    $less->checkedCompile("stylesheet.less", "stylesheet.css");
?>
```

and all you have to do is work with your less file and php will do the rest =')